# Why Does not Attacking From Above Make Sense at The Battle of Bothawui

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

At the beginning of the Battle of Bothawui during the Clone Wars, General Grievous makes a comment how, if the Separatist fleet attacks from above, the Republic will have the advantage, therefore, he must go through the asteroid belt, which leaves his capital ships vulnerable to attacks from behind, and of course, the Republic attacks from behind, and his forces are beaten. My question is, why does not attacking from above make any since. How does this give the Republic an advantage?(This is from the Clone Wars, Season 1, episode 6)

[Battle of Bothawui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywBZNZEr8q8)

Comment: We can invent pseudo-plausible reasons for you, but ultimately the answer is "because plot". Not enough information is given in-universe to do anything else.

Comment: @amflare I think that, when no good canon answer exists, the answer "no good canon answer exists" is a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separatist had 6 [Munificent-class frigates](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Munificent-class_star_frigate) . One of those was [Grievous command ship](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Grievous%27s_Munificent-class_star_frigate_%28Bothawui%29). By the looks of it, main firepower of those ships was aimed forward (twin turbo-laser cannon) and it could not be depressed to attack below. Also, bottom of these frigates looks vulnerable  - no "armor" as on top side and again cannons could not be fully depressed to fire directly below. Apparently Republic walkers took advantage of that and crippled those frigates as they passed above them.

[image]

[image]

Republic had 3 [Venator-class Star Destroyers](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Venator-class_Star_Destroyer). Those ships look sturdy from above.

[image]

I guess Grievous didn't want to expose vulnerable underbelly of his ships to Republic fire, while at the same time facing armored top part of Republic cruisers. So he pressed forward trough asteroid filed, but he was forced to divert all power to forward shields in order to minimize damage from asteroid hits. This opened chance for Republic walkers stationed below his fleet.